# Разность двоичных чисел

Tags: битовые-операции, java

Привет.

Сделал побитово сложение двоичных чисел, а вот как сделать разность двух двоичных чисел, а именно когда уменьшаемое меньше вычитаемого, например, 10-111 (в двоичной системе), когда в конце занять уже не у кого. Мне нужно, чтобы в ответе было отрицательное. Не пойму, как это можно организовать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Записывайте двоичное представление числа в [дополнительном коде](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4_%28%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%29). Тогда вы сможете заменить вычитание `A - B` на сложение `A + (-B)`. Изменение знака у числа в дополнительном коде осуществляется инверсией его битов и прибавлением 1. После осуществления операции вычитания не забудьте правильно (с учётом дополнительного кода) проинтерпретировать результат. В вашем случае вычитание будет выглядеть так:

1. Записываем `-111` в дополнительном коде. Для этого инвертируем исходное число (`000`) и прибавляем 1 (`001`). В старший разряд записываем 1 (это означает, что число отрицательное), получаем `1001`.
2. Складываем `10 + 1001 = 1011`.
3. Помним, что `1011` - запись числа в дополнительном коде. Старший разряд отвечает за знак: 1 - это `-`, 0 - это `+`. Если старший разряд `0`, то он отбрасывается, а остальное число интерпретируется как положительное. Если старший разряд `1`, то число отрицательное, и его нужно инвертировать также, как мы сделали это с исходным числом. То есть, `1011 -> 011 -> 100 -> 101`. Получаем `10 - 111 = -101` (`2 - 7 = -5`) в прямом коде или `0010 + 1001 = 1011` в дополнительном.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужен не дополнительный код, а просто двоичное число с знаком, то просто проверяйте два числа и если первое меньше второго (Ваша ситуация), то меняйте их местами, вычитайте, просто к результату приписывайте минус.